# Вывод NaN при подсчете (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Проблема - при выводе на одной странице 2-х однотипный блоков подсчет не ведется корректно, при выводе только одного блока всё нормально.

Как сделать корректную калькуляцию более одного такого блока, при любых их количествах (могут добавляться через CMS)?

ВОзможно нужна более грамотная выборка в скрипте? Но что то не могу догадаться как это реализовать. Вод собственно код:

```js
var price_5 = $('p.price__5 span').text();
var price_4 = parseInt(price_4).toFixed(2);

var price_4 = price_5 * 0.9;
var res_4 = price_4.toFixed(2);
var price_3 = price_5 * 0.8;
var res_3 = price_3.toFixed(2);
var price_2 = price_5 * 0.7;
var res_2 = price_2.toFixed(2);
var price_1 = price_5 * 0.6;
var res_1 = price_1.toFixed(2);

$('p.price__4 span').html(res_4);
$('p.price__3 span').html(res_3);
$('p.price__2 span').html(res_2);
$('p.price__1 span').html(res_1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card__description card__description_right">

  <div class="card__wrap_form card__wrap_amount">
    <div class="card__price">
      <p class="price__one price__1">Цена 1 - <span></span> руб.</p>
      <p class="price__one price__2">Цена 2 - <span></span> руб.</p>
      <p class="price__one price__3">Цена 3 - <span></span> руб.</p>
      <p class="price__one price__4">Цена 4 - <span></span> руб.</p>
      <p class="price__one price__5">Цена 5 - <span>20.00</span> руб.</p>
      <!-- <p class="price__total">на 990 ₽</p> -->
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="card__wrap_form card__wrap_amount">
    <div class="card__price">
      <p class="price__one price__1">Цена 1 - <span></span> руб.</p>
      <p class="price__one price__2">Цена 2 - <span></span> руб.</p>
      <p class="price__one price__3">Цена 3 - <span></span> руб.</p>
      <p class="price__one price__4">Цена 4 - <span></span> руб.</p>
      <p class="price__one price__5">Цена 5 - <span>20.00</span> руб.</p>
      <!-- <p class="price__total">на 990 ₽</p> -->
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу проблему с типом данных, в переменной `price_5` вы храните string.
`var price_5 = parseInt($('p.price__5 span').text());` в данном примере решает проблему.

Comment: Да, помогло, вот только price__5 считается из первого блока и во все остальные результаты подсчетов записываются из первого блока как раз)

Comment: Всё верно, вы же не указали из какого блока брать данный `$('p.price__5 span').text()` берёт данные из первого совпадения. Для работы второго блока надо либо менять в нём идентификаторы, либо переписывать метод.

Comment: Иван, спасибо, оттолкнуться теперь есть от чего, сейчас буду думать

Comment: Собираете все card__price в массив, и в цикле работаете со всем что внутри.